# Ajax Facebook Like & Sharethis Postback Problem

Tags: c#, ajax, facebook

I am having problems displaying both Facebook Like and Sharethis widgets to show up on postback event, initial load displays them perfectly, but as soon as page invokes partial postback and since both widgets are wrapped in update pannel, the elements disappear from the page.

Note: I tried the iframe solution for the facebook like button, which is now giving me another problem with not being able to reach the page, even though with current method outside of the update panel it's working correctly.

any help would be appreciated.